# Chrome tab with Firestore crashes with error code 11

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

I try to add a document to Firestore in the online console. I auto-id the document, add just a single character to the field and its value, and hit 'Save'. This causes always my Chrome tab to crash with error code 11 and nothing gets saved. It used to work without any problems and Firestore works fine in another browser and for my colleagues.

I tried rebooting my Chrome and clearing my Cookies and site data but this didn't resolve the issue.

What might cause the problem and how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Grammarly plugin interfered here. After disabling the plugin, everything works really well again.